# How are these residue calculus questions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Why are these asked in the section about residue/cauchy calculus

$$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{cos(\theta)}{2+cos(\theta)} d\theta$$

or

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{sin(\theta)}{2+cos(\theta)} d\theta$$

Because isn't the denominator never equal to zero anyways? So why do we need to integrate over countours?

Comment: Because they're ideal problems for contour integration. Perhaps you should take a look at a textbook or video, there's tons in YouTube.

Comment: @Kaynex please explain why they're ideal problems -- it's very easy to solve these without using any contour integration methods, so why bother using them?

Comment: The idea is to set $z=e^{i\theta}$, so that the integral is over the unit circle $\{z:|z|=1\}$, and for instance $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$.

Comment: Because there's examples like this that are impossible to solve without it.

Comment: done hunderds of times on this site